# Angular Fire Use $$added

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I am using Firebase angularFire.
I want to track event on child added.
My code is like this :
        v

```
var notifyRef = new Firebase(CONFIG[ENV]['FIREBASE_NOTIFICATION_URL']+$rootScope.user.id+'/unseen');

notificationEvent.$$added(function(snap,val){
console.log(snap)
        })
```

But it is giving me error.where am i going wrong.

Comment: What error are you getting and what is notificationEvent?

Comment: There is no `$$added()`` on a Firebase reference. You're probably looking to do this: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/extending-services.html